Unable to update the value of Basic Text Field
I was building an app the uses Basic Text Field. When I try to update the value of Basic Text Field, it won't work unless you recompose it.
val textX = remember{ mutableStateOf("Text")}


BasicTextField(
            value = textX.value,
            onValueChange = {
                textX.value = it
                            }  )

Text(text = textX.value)


When the textX change in other place of code, it won't update on the Basic Text Field, but it updates in Text composable Live.
But when i try to recompose by navigating to other screen and come back, it will display correctly.
But it's obvious that it can be updated on the UI.
I have tried using "by" but not working.

Please create a minimal reproducible example. It's hard to help without reproducing the issue.

Consider using var textX by remember { mutableStateOf("") } In that case, it is not necessary to use value, just the variable name: onValueChange = { textX = it } and  Text(text = textX)  It should work like this. There are differences between = and by. Please read the documentation and write your code following the examples.

You are using a val which can only be set to a value once, instead of a var which allows the value to be updated multiple times.
OPTIONAL: instead of this:
val textX = remember{ mutableStateOf("Text")}

Use the by setter:
val textX by remember{ mutableStateOf("Text")}

